# Google Apps Script Forms - Failed to add item. You have reached the maximum number of items

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm making an extensive phone trade in form. The form asks for the Manufacturer (Apple), the model  (iPhone 6), the capacity (32GB), the carrier (Verizon), and the condition (Good). In order to provide an instant quote to the customer, this form essentially needs to become a top down tree, so Apple alone will have hundreds of possible combinations of final quote pages (quotes updated via script now and then). What is the specific item limit? I cannot seem to find any documentation on Google Forms item limits. Is there a way to get around this limit or work within its confines for my use-case?

[image: Failed to add item]

Below is all of my code, minus the data for manufacturers other than Apple. Some of the if-statements are to handle situations where the data structure for other manufacturers differs than that presented below (ie phones with no carrier specifications, or no GB specifications, or both).

```
function populateForm() {
  var manufacturers = {
    'Apple':{
      'iPhone 5':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 5c':{
        '8GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 5s':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 6':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 6 Plus':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 6s':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 6s Plus':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 7':{
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 7 Plus':{
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 8':{
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone 8 Plus':{
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone SE':{
        '16GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '32GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone X':{
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone XR':{
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '128GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone XS':{
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '512GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      },
      'iPhone XS Max':{
        '64GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '256GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        },
        '512GB':{
          'Unlocked':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'AT&T':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Sprint':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'T-Mobile':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Verizon':['Good','Poor','Faulty'],
          'Unknown':['Good','Poor','Faulty']
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var form = FormApp.openById('1WKOOpA54BVt71PHpSL5FcTkFJ3C-dYRFEXIvtgDBE6g');
  var selectManufacturer = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)[0].asMultipleChoiceItem();
  var selectManufacturerArray = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)[0].asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices();
  var key = 'Apple' //this was for (key in manufacturers) {} but now each manufacturer needs to be done individually to get around 5 minute timeout
  var manufacturerSection = form.addPageBreakItem(); //Apple, Samsung, Sony
  manufacturerSection.setTitle(key); //maybe add 'Which iphone do you have' specific sentences from within manufacturers table
  var selectModel = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  selectModel.setTitle('Which phone do you have?');
  var selectModelArray = [];
  for (var key2 in manufacturers[key]) {
    var modelSection = form.addPageBreakItem(); //iPhone 5, Samsung S6, Xperia 1 //decide for next nested elements. 3 options: dictionary with GB, dictionary with cell provider, array with condition
    if (Array.isArray(manufacturers[key][key2]) === true) {
      //value of key2 is an array, indicating no GB or carrier specification, straigh to condition
      //Good Poor Faulty
      Logger.log('Good Poor Faulty');
      var goodCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
      goodCondition.setTitle('Good');
      goodCondition.setHelpText('• Everything works as it should\n• No major damage (i.e. chips or cracks to the screen or phone)\n• No water damage\n• Light wear and tear acceptable');
      var poorCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
      poorCondition.setTitle('Poor');
      poorCondition.setHelpText('• Everything works as it should\n• Heavy wear and tear, such as scuffs, dents, and deep scratches');
      var faultyCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
      faultyCondition.setTitle('Faulty');
      faultyCondition.setHelpText('• Major software/hardware issues (i.e. the phone freezes/crashes regularly)\n• Significant physical damage\n• Faulty screen (including cracks, discoloration, and damaged pixels)\n• Water damage\n• Please note: we cannot buy your phone if it is missing components or is bent, crushed, or snapped in half.');
      var selectCondition = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      selectCondition.setTitle('Please specify what condition the device is in.');
      var selectConditionArray = [];
      for (var key3 in manufacturers[key][key2]) {
        var conditionSection = form.addPageBreakItem();
        conditionSection.setTitle(manufacturers[key][key2][key3]);
        selectConditionArray.push(selectCondition.createChoice(manufacturers[key][key2][key3], conditionSection));
      }
      selectCondition.setChoices(selectConditionArray);
    } else if (Object.keys(manufacturers[key][key2])[0].indexOf('GB')+1 > 0) { //.includes('GB') isn't yet supported in GAS, so this workaround returns 0 if substring not present in string. also Object.keys({...})[0] gets the first key in the dictionary type object to check if it is a memory capacity or cell carrier dictionary. indexOf is CASE-SENSITIVE
      if (Array.isArray(manufacturers[key][key2][Object.keys(manufacturers[key][key2])[0]]) === true) {
        //value of key2 is a dictionary with elements that contain GB AND the next sub-object is an array for device conditions
        //64GB, Good Poor Faulty, do stuff
        Logger.log('64GB, Good Poor Faulty');
        var selectCapacity = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        selectCapacity.setTitle('Please select the storage capacity of your phone');
        var selectCapacityArray = [];
        for (var key3 in manufacturers[key][key2]) {
          var capacitySection = form.addPageBreakItem();
          capacitySection.setTitle(key3);
          var goodCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
          goodCondition.setTitle('Good');
          goodCondition.setHelpText('• Everything works as it should\n• No major damage (i.e. chips or cracks to the screen or phone)\n• No water damage\n• Light wear and tear acceptable');
          var poorCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
          poorCondition.setTitle('Poor');
          poorCondition.setHelpText('• Everything works as it should\n• Heavy wear and tear, such as scuffs, dents, and deep scratches');
          var faultyCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
          faultyCondition.setTitle('Faulty');
          faultyCondition.setHelpText('• Major software/hardware issues (i.e. the phone freezes/crashes regularly)\n• Significant physical damage\n• Faulty screen (including cracks, discoloration, and damaged pixels)\n• Water damage\n• Please note: we cannot buy your phone if it is missing components or is bent, crushed, or snapped in half.');
          var selectCondition = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
          selectCondition.setTitle('Please sepcify what condition the device is in.');
          var selectConditionArray = [];
          for (var key4 in manufacturers[key][key2][key3]) {
            var conditionSection = form.addPageBreakItem();
            conditionSection.setTitle(manufacturers[key][key2][key3][key4]);
            selectConditionArray.push(selectCondition.createChoice(manufacturers[key][key2][key3][key4], conditionSection));
          }
          selectCondition.setChoices(selectConditionArray);
          selectCapacityArray.push(selectCapacity.createChoice(key3, capacitySection)); //use key as value for dictionaries, and use dictionary[index] structure for arrays
        }
        selectCapacity.setChoices(selectCapacityArray);
      } else {
        //value of key2 is a dictionary with elements that contain GB AND the next sub-object is another dictionary that is for cell carriers, followed by a last sub-object of an array for device conditions
        //64GB, Verizon AT&T T-Mobile, Good Poor Faulty, do stuff
        Logger.log('64GB, Verizon AT&T T-Mobile, Good Poor Faulty');
        var selectCapacity = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        selectCapacity.setTitle('Please select the storage capacity of your phone');
        var selectCapacityArray = [];
        for (var key3 in manufacturers[key][key2]) {
          var capacitySection = form.addPageBreakItem();
          capacitySection.setTitle(key3);
          var selectCarrier = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
          selectCarrier.setTitle('Please select the cell carrier of your phone');
          var selectCarrierArray = [];
          for (var key4 in manufacturers[key][key2][key3]) {
            var carrierSection = form.addPageBreakItem();
            carrierSection.setTitle(key4);
            var goodCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
            goodCondition.setTitle('Good');
            goodCondition.setHelpText('• Everything works as it should\n• No major damage (i.e. chips or cracks to the screen or phone)\n• No water damage\n• Light wear and tear acceptable');
            var poorCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
            poorCondition.setTitle('Poor');
            poorCondition.setHelpText('• Everything works as it should\n• Heavy wear and tear, such as scuffs, dents, and deep scratches');
            var faultyCondition = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
            faultyCondition.setTitle('Faulty');
            faultyCondition.setHelpText('• Major software/hardware issues (i.e. the phone freezes/crashes regularly)\n• Significant physical damage\n• Faulty screen (including cracks, discoloration, and damaged pixels)\n• Water damage\n• Please note: we cannot buy your phone if it is missing components or is bent, crushed, or snapped in half.');
            var selectCondition = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
            selectCondition.setTitle('Please specify what condition the device is in.');
            var selectConditionArray = [];
            for (var key5 in manufacturers[key][key2][key3][key4]) {
              var conditionSection = form.addPageBreakItem();
              conditionSection.setTitle(manufacturers[key][key2][key3][key4][key5]);
              selectConditionArray.push(selectCondition.createChoice(manufacturers[key][key2][key3][key4][key5], conditionSection));
            }
            selectCondition.setChoices(selectConditionArray);
            selectCarrierArray.push(selectCarrier.createChoice(key4, carrierSection));
          }
          selectCarrier.setChoices(selectCarrierArray);
          selectCapacityArray.push(selectCapacity.createChoice(key3, capacitySection));
        }
        selectCapacity.setChoices(selectCapacityArray);
      }
    } else {
      //value of key2 is a dictionary with elements that DO NOT contain GB, indicating that there are no storage capacity choices, and direct to cell carrier choices, followed by a last sub-object of an array for device conditions
      //Verizon AT&T T-Mobile, Good Poor Faulty, do stuff
      Logger.log('Verizon AT&T T-Mobile, Good Poor Faulty');
      //NOT DONE - NOT WRITTEN YET
    }
    modelSection.setTitle(key2);
    selectModelArray.push(selectModel.createChoice(key2, modelSection));
  }
  selectModel.setChoices(selectModelArray);
  if (selectManufacturerArray[0].getValue() === '') {
    selectManufacturerArray[0] = selectManufacturer.createChoice(key, manufacturerSection); //creating a multiple choice item automatically fills in an empty choice, so replace it with a real choice first before adding into
  } else {
    selectManufacturerArray.push(selectManufacturer.createChoice(key, manufacturerSection));
  }
  selectManufacturer.setChoices(selectManufacturerArray);
}
```

Comment: Why not make a multi choice grid?

Comment: @TheMaster Multichoice row would be good if I could limit to one response per grid, but it only allows limits on one response per row. Also it does not allow for "Go to section based on answer"

Comment: I have hit the same limitation with a maximum number of items of around 1001, despite the total number of cells allowed in the response spreadsheet documented to be 5,000,000

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script works until it throws you the error message, so you can easily find out the limit yourself by opening the Form and seeing how many items you created.

If your Form is linked to a Spreadsheet that stores the results, there is a documented [limit](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E7sT_BMkFOXR4EsDMUUhOgeD6BrEjFzS8fHv8tNrfPU/edit) of max. 400 000 cells per spreadsheet.

When it comes to a workaround for your case - attach your form to a spreadsheet, open the spreadsheet and have a look what the Form Responses look like:

[image]

You populate the sheet with an infinite repetition of the same question, because of the way how you assign multiply nested array values to the item titles and choices.

Have a look at the [Form Service References for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/). 
You can reduce your number of items significantly, by creating independent, rather than nested questions:

```
function populateForm() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('Id of your form');    
    form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheet.getId());
    var item = form.addCheckboxItem();

    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
        .setTitle('What is your phone model?')
        .setChoiceValues([('iPhone 6', 'iPhone 5', ...])

    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
       .setTitle('What is your phone capacity?')
       .setChoiceValues([('32GB', '64GB', ...])

  ...   
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the new limit is 5 million: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en

Comment: The reason I created nested questions was to provide instant price quotations for the customer from the Google Form. With independent questions, I am unable to do this because Forms does not have the ability to analyze the responses of previous questions and direct the customer to a specific page with a correct price quotation. I know this creates a convoluted form structure, but I figured it would be easiest for the end-user. I suppose I could use the form structure you recommended and have a script email them the quote instead. Perhaps there are more advanced form builders I should consider?

Comment: If you link your form to a spreadsheet, you can bind to this spreadsheet an Apps Script with algorithms that will calculate the quote based on the user input and then email it to the user. You can incorporate it within an onEdit() trigger function, so that the code will be run directly ,every time the sheet will be updated with information from every new submitted form.